# Several string inputs for one variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement, input

Is there any other way to shorten this condition?

```
if (oper.equals("add") || oper.equals("Add") || oper.equals("addition") ||
oper.equals("Addition") || oper.equals("+"))
```

I was just wondering if there's something I can do to 'shortcut' this. The user will type a string when prompted what kind of operation is to be performed in my simple calculator program. Our professor said our program should accept whether the user enters "add", or "Add", you know, in lowercase letters or not... Or is the only way I should do it?

Comment: Perhaps put the alternative words in a List/array and do a contains()/loop. To allow capital letters, simply convert all input to lowercase (or uppercase) before parsing it, or use equalsIgnoreCase, as suggested below.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) for 1st four strings: -

```
if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("add") || 
    oper.equalsIgnoreCase("addition") || 
    oper.equals("+"))
```

If number of strings increases, you would be better off with a `List`, and use its `contains` method. But just for these inputs, you can follow this approach only.

---

Another way to approach this is to use [`String#matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method, which takes a regex: -

```
if (oper.matches("add|addition|[+]")
```

But, you don't really need a regex for this. Specially, this method can become ugly for greater inputs. But, it's just a way for this case. So, you can choose either of them. 1st one is more clear to watch on first go.

---

Alternatively, you can also use [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to store `operators`, and pass it's instance everywhere, rather than a `string`. It would be more easy to work with. The enum would look like this:

```
public enum Operator {
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MUL,
    DIV;
}
```

You can enhance it to your appropriate need. Note that, since you are getting user input, you would first need to identify the appropriate enum instance based on it, and from there-on you can work on that enum instance, rather than String.

Comment: +1 I liked `another` approach. it's not that difficult to understand(`1st one is more clear to watch on first go.`)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale.. Yeah right. But, just in case someone is not comfortable with `Regex`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Rohit's answer, I would like to add this.

In case of comparison of strings, if `oper is null` a `NullPointerException` could be thrown. SO its always better to write

```
"addition".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)
```

instead of

```
oper.equalsIgnoreCase("addition")
```

Answer (score 3):

If `aDD` is considered as invalid input, you can consider following approach:

```
ArrayList<String> possibleInputs = new ArrayList<String>();

possibleInputs.add("Add");
possibleInputs.add("add");
possibleInputs.add("Addition");
possibleInputs.add("addition");
possibleInputs.add("+");

if(possibleInputs.contains(oper))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use equalsIgnoreCase() then?

Comment: `possibleInputs.**Add**()`??? There is not such method in `List`. Gosh, there is `2 upvotes` on this.

Comment: You can use `String#toLowerCase()` method, to avoid adding both `"add"` and `"Add"` in your list. You can assume that `aDD` is not invalid, as it's not listed in OP.

Comment: @RohitJain: that's what happens when you miz languages. :( .. corrected. thanks.

Comment: @Azodious.. C# earlier probably?? I'm just guessing. Anyways, happens :)

Comment: yup, was following C# naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

throw that whole bit of code inside a function called: `isOperationAddition(String s){...}` that returns a boolean.

So this:

```
if (oper.equals("add") || oper.equals("Add") || oper.equals("addition") ||
    oper.equals("Addition") || oper.equals("+")){...}
```

Changes to this

```
if (isOperationAddition(operation)){...}
```

Then inside that method, don't use Strings as branch material for your if statements.  Have a variable that defines which kind of operation it is and "Keep the barbarians (confusion/ambiguous users) out at the moat".  You should not be always iterating against a list to remember what operation we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input, and convert in to lower case then compare.

```
str.toLowerCase()
```

then pass to your if() statement

```
if(str.equals("add") || str.equals("addition") || str.equals("+"))
```